# jQuery detect if non-form element (nav menu item) has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

On a home page, I have a menu bar that is invisible (i.e. offscreen above the visible area) on pageload and is moved down (animated) from the top as soon as the scroll position goes beyond 50px to appear as a regular (fixed) nav menu bar. This is done with jQuery. The menu bar moves up/disappears again when the page is fully scrolled up to the top.

But for accessibility reasons, the menu should also appear when someone uses the tab key several times to focus and select the menu items in that navbar (without scrolling).

As a first test, I tried this function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#menu-item-55').focus(function() {
                 alert("yes!");
    });
});
```

(Later on this should trigger the animation that brings the menu into the visible area of the page)

This test function works if I use it on a form field that gets focus, but it doesn't work on a link in the nav menu, apparently because `focus()` only works on form elements.

Is there any way to either make that also work for a link, or is there any other method that lets me detect the focus on a link?

Comment: Try using `.mouseenter()` or `.click()` instead of `.focus()`.

Comment: @PHPglue thanks, I tried it, but that won't work on focus, only on "real" mouseenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer myself:

`focus()` won't work on links, but `focusin()` *does*!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 1.6+ then you can use the [:focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#menu-item-55').is(':focus')) {
        alert("yes!");
    });
});
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer.  CSS :focus will work so GumZ's answer should work as well.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, but that doesn't work here